How to access postgresql database running on Docker volume from database client
I have an asp.net (version 8) webapi project that I have set up to work with docker.
I have the container that runs my API and a volume where I put my database.
It works and I'm able to run API endpoints to get my data from the postgresql database.
I want to be able to view the database running in the volume though.
How can I do this?
I'm using a Visual Studio Code plugin called PostgreSQL (Postgresql management tool by Chris Kolkman) and I can connect to the postgresql database I installed on my operating system but not the one that is running on my docker volume.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file
services:
 #asp.net web application
  webapp:
    container_name: shop-back-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5999:5999"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - Database__ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Host=db;Port=5432;Database=shopback;Username=postgres;Password=XXXXX


  #postreSQL database
  db:
    container_name: shop-back-db
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: shopback
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: XXXXX
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      

I also have the "Docker" extension installed and I can view my images, containers, and volumes from Visual Studio Code but I'm not sure if this can help me as it doesn't give me access to the database running on my volume.

What connection information are you trying to use in the VS Code extension?  Are you also running a non-container database, and is it also listening on the standard PostgreSQL port 5432?  (I don't think the Docker volume is especially related to this issue.)

All I had to do was uninstall the postgresql server installed on my OS and I was then able to connect to the postgresql server running on the Docker volume right away.

So you've already discovered that it was a conflict with the ports.

I discovered it was a conflict with the ports after creating this post.  Thank you for your input.

I have tried to access a Postgresql database in a Docker container from Visual Studio Code and it works correctly.
The only thing to keep in mind is the Postgres configuration. Consider enabling the IP where the database listens. Inside the container, make sure that PostgreSQL is configured to accept connections from any address (listen_addresses = '*' in postgresql.conf and setting the access rules in pg_hba.conf).
And if you already have Postgresql running on your computer, consider changing the access port so that there are no conflicts, since you will have to access with the address 127.0.0.1:5432
